# C more arguments than required scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I have a while loop with `scanf()` that reads in a single char* value:

```
char c[9];

while(c != 'q')
{
    scanf("%s", c);
}
```

`c` is then compared with multiple one-character strings to determine which operation should be performed.

This scanf can receive multiple arguments and I need to know when only one argument is provided to the function or if there are multiple arguments, but whenever I type in more than one argument, the while loop is run separately for each argument entered.

---

#### Edit:

So say I enter something like "a b c d", the while loop will process `c="a"`, `c="b"`, `c="c"`, and `c="d"`, which is fine, but I need to know that I entered 4 non-white-space elements in the last scan.

So the first argument is the command I am going to run which is a letter, followed by between 0 and 3 arguments for that command, which are strings or numbers:

Example:

```
"a box 1 2"
```

When the number of arguments are fixed, I just used a boolean value to know that the next x values of c are supposed to be the arguments, but I have one function which can accept 0 or 1 arguments, e.g.

```
"b" is acceptable.
"b 25" is acceptable.
```

`b` is basically a search function where the optional argument is the query to check against. If no argument is provided, it lists all items. So a boolean value won't work in this case because the number of arguments is not fixed.

So I need to know that if I enter:

```
"a 1 2 3"  x=4
"a 1"      x=2
"a"        x=1
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You know how many arguments are supplied to `scanf`, since you wrote the code. Anyway, the number of conversions is dependent on the format string, not the other arguments. If you pass more arguments than required, the extra ones will just be ignored.

Comment: In this case, `scanf()` has always exactly two arguments. The way to determine how many arguments a function is receiving is to **look at your code** and search with your eyeballs for the function call in question. Also, your comparison of an array of `char`s to a single `char` makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @Barmar Basically the scanf function is allowing me to input more than one argument for that function, and whenever I do, it loops through the while loop for each argument separately, so I have no way of knowing how many arguments were originally supplied to the scanf.

Comment: @David, would it help to change 'char c[9];' to 'char c;' and use 'scanf("%c", &c);' instead?

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer No

Comment: @David You're still not making any sense. Are you talking about the number of arguments to the function that contains the code you showed? Unless it's a varargs function, it has to be called with the exact number of arguments in its prototype.

Comment: @Barmar So I have a while loop that runs this scanf. I have multiple arguments that I give it separated by spaces. Since the scanf only asks for 1 argument, when 2 or more are inputted, the while loop is run for each argument that I give it. So for example, if I put in "a b", it runs the while loop where c="a" and where c="b". Because of this, there's no way for me to know how many arguments were passed to scanf because it returns 1 each time it goes through the loop. Do you know how I can find out how many arguments were given to scanf?

Comment: 1 argument is passed to `scanf` each time through the loop. If you want to know how many times the loop was run, increment a counter.

Comment: @Barmar But the loop will run until it runs out of arguments and then it waits at the scanf input again. How do I know before it gets to the scanf again that it has exhausted the input given to it?

Comment: @David, perhaps when reading with 'scanf("%s", c);', it is only reading one argument at a time, it also seeing a space as a delimiter?

Comment: Your comparison is not correct. You can't compare a string with a character. And if you want to compare strings, you have to use `strcmp()`.

Comment: It appears you want to enter a _line_ of text like "a b c d\n", code then determines there are 4 non-white-space `char` arguments each of length one: 'a', b', 'c', 'd'.  It then processes those 4 and repeats or stops.  Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate IO from scanning/parsing.

```
char buf[100];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
int count = 0;  // Count of arguments.
char *p = buf;

while (*p) {
  if (!isspace((unsigned char) *p)) {
    count++;
    // Do something, if desired with *p
  }
  else {
    Handle_UnexpectedWhiteSpaceChar();
  }
  if (isspace((unsigned char) *p)) {
    p++;
  }
  else {
    Handle_UnexpectedTwoNonSpaceChar();
  }
```

Comment: This looks promising.

Comment: There are a number of ways to approach this.  Challenges include that a line-of-text is not a C string and coping with evil user IO is best done separately from parsing/scanning.  Strongly recommend never use `scanf()` as it combines IO with parsing and does neither well.

Comment: @David `fgets()` does an OK job at reading a line-of-text and forming a C string.  BTW GTG

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to type a series of numbers on each line, until you enter `q`.

```
char line[1024] = "";
int nums[MAXNUMS];
int counter = 0;
while (strcmp(line, "q\n") != 0) {
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    while (counter < MAXNUMS && sscanf("%d", &nums[counter])) {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: So where do I reference `counter` when the end of input is reached? Won't the scanner continue to scan until I exit the program?

Comment: The loop stops when the user enters `q`.

Comment: Okay I guess this is where I was misunderstood. This loop is supposed to continue until q is entered, but say I input a 1 2 3 into the scanner, I need to know that I just entered 4 elements; I most likely will not be exiting the loop after entering those 4 elements, so how do I get the count?

Comment: @David What are the _4_ elements of inputing 1 2 3?

Comment: @chux it was "a 1 2 3"